# drupal 7 image style error with php max upload size

Tags: image, drupal-7, styles, image-uploading, php-ini

There is issue while uploading image more 5M with high quality , Image style can not create image or something else (i have no idea what is happening with it) .

```
2015/08/11 11:43:51 [error] 17642#0: *1513886 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 15360 bytes) in /system/image.gd.inc on line 232" while reading response header from upstream, client: "server ip adress", server: hostname.domain, request: "GET 044a8109_fu_ben_.jpg?itok=u19u-70Y HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/web156.sock:", host: "hostname.domain", referrer: "domain/product/379"
```

In server max upload size : 128M , for image field max upload size is 50M, But not showing uploaded images.

In Chrome browser console so error shows:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/25531... Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).
```

Second image is after creating content .

Comment: **There is  first image of this**  [first image](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/1_75.png)

Comment: **There is second image of this** [second image](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2_58.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have exceded you `memory_limit`. Check `php.ini` file for you `memory_limit` and upadate as necessary.

[This may help.](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/managing-site-performance-and-scalability/changing-php-memory-limits)